# how to make Ctrl+L visual studio short cut key work with the Right Control button

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I use CTRL+L key stroke very frequently to quickly cut and copy a line in Visual Studio.Net. 
However this key combination does not work with the Right control Key button on a regular windows keyboard. It works only with the Left Control button.

```
(LEFT) CTRL + L --> Works
(RIGHT) CTRL + L --> Does not works
```

How to make RIGHT CTRL button to behave like the LEFT CTRL button so the key combinations work fine.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Define "regular" - it works fine for me.

Comment: Its the standard windows keyboard (eg: http://www.solidtekusa.com/image/260BU.jpg)

Comment: So, a US layout 104-key, windows keyboard?

Comment: Yes it would be US layout 104-key, windows keyboard